# What statistical test should I use? (GLMM and comparing 4 groups)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I'm analyzing the following case: I have a continuous response variable (named Vueltasmin), that allows positive, negative and null values, and factors as explanatory values (the explanatory variable is named Condicion).

I thought of running a GLMM, as I have dependent data (one subject was measured more than once, hence the variable Bicho, that stands for the subject), but:

1. My response variable is more likely to have positive and zero values than negative ones, so I can't assume the residuals would be normally distributed.
2. I can't use zero-inflated models as my response variable is not countable, but continuous.
3. I can't use a gamma-distribution as my variable allows negative values.

What should I do?

I'm using R to run my tests, so any hints on how to perform your suggestions in that environment would be very appreciated!

Here is how my plot looks like, after choosing the adequate model I wish to perform some specific comparisons:

- red vs grey
- red vs black
- red vs light blue
- black vs grey.
  [image]

Here is the code I'm running, and below the graphs for testing assumptions:

```
m1 <- lmer(Vueltasmin ~ Condicion + (1 | Bicho), Datos)
e1<-resid(m1) #  pearson´s residues
pre1<-predict(m1) #predicted
windows()
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(pre1, e1, xlab="Predichos", ylab="Residuos de pearson",main="Gráfico de             
dispersión de RE vs PRED",cex.main=.8 ) 
abline(0,0)
qqnorm(e1, cex.main=.9)   #QQ plot
qqline(e1)
windows()
hist(e1)
```

[image]

Comment: The discussion here might be useful https://www.researchgate.net/post/Negative_values_in_multiple_regression_analysis

Comment: Characteristic (1) does not rule out normally distributed residuals.  The distribution of the residuals typically is nothing like the distribution of the response.  You still could use a zero-inflated model--that does not require a discrete response--but you haven't presented any reason to.

Comment: Hi whuber!  in this case both the response variable and it's residuals aren´t normally distributed, hence my question. I was taught that zero inflated models applied to discrete response variables (Poisson regression, wich is suitable for a  countable variable).
What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Could you fit an ANOVA and show us a plot of the residuals? As whuber says, it's not at all clear that you need to make your model more complex than that.

Comment: Hi MKT and Whuber, I updated the post with the GLMM and the residual's graph. I didn't use ANOVA as I lack independence of datapoints (every subject was tested in all six conditions).